# nth set of accumulation points is empty

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to prove the following:

For every positive integer $n,$ there is $A\subset{\mathbb{R}}$ such that $A,A^{1},A^{2},...,A^{n-1}$ are nonempty and $A^{n}=\emptyset.$ (The result can be extended to countable ordinals. Let $A^{\alpha}=(A^{\alpha-1})'$ if $\alpha$ is a nonlimit ordinal, $A^{\alpha}=(\bigcap_{\beta<\alpha}A^{\beta})'$ if $\alpha$ is an ordinal limit, and show that for any $\alpha<\omega_{1},$ a set $A$ can be finding such that $A^{\alpha}=\emptyset$ and $A^{\beta}\neq{\emptyset}$ for $\beta<\alpha$).

Here $A^{1}=(A)'$ is the set accumulation points of $A.$ Then $A^{2}=(A^{1})^{'}$ and so on.

$\omega_{1}$ is the first uncountable ordinal.

I am stuck with this. For the case $n=1$ is enough consider a non-constant convergent sequence, but for the other cases, I have only found cases in which the set of accumulation points is uncountable ( intervals ) with no empty set accumulation points or countable sets with empty set as accumulation point. Building sets with finite accumulation points is no problem, but asked the required property is strange.

Any kind of help is thanked in advanced.

Comment: Maybe the keyword Cantor-Bendixon rank will help you in some way. 

I remember that I looked (and found ) for a description of countable closed bounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ of any given successor cardinal Cantor-Bendixon rank, in the past. I unfortunately don't remenber the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n = 1:\{0\}$
For $n = 2:\{ 1/n : n\in\Bbb N\}\cup\{0\}$
For $n = 3:\{ 1/n + 1/m : n,m\in\Bbb N\}\cup\{ 1/n : n\in\Bbb N\}\cup\{0\}$

The idea is to take the sequence $(1/n)_n$ and for
each point $1/n$ create a sequence with limit of $1/n$.

This construction can be extended to any finite $n$.

Comment: You're using the symbol $n$ for two different things.

Comment: @AndreasBlass.  I am not.  The variable n inside the set definition is bound and can be replaced by any other variable.  The free occurance of n out side the set cannot be replaced by another variable because it specifically refers to the n of your question.

Comment: Thanks @WilliamElliot. That was helpful.

Comment: It might a good idea to at least make it plausible why those sets don't have 'unwanted' accumulation points. Getting the idea is straitghforward, making sure you don't have 'to many' points is the main problem.

Comment: You wrote "I am not" but then you explained exactly the difference between the two uses of $n$, once as a free variable and once as a bound variable. I agree that the bound occurrences can be replaced by another variable, and I would add that they should be.